# How to write to BigTable using Apache Beam direct-runner in java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I have been trying to get Apache Beam direct runner to write to BigTable but it seems like there is a problem.

There is no failure or confirmation errors on the terminal when I run `gradle run`.

My pipeline is as follows:

`Pub/Sub stream of messages -> direct-runner -> BigTable`

Currently using `org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigtable.BigtableIO` adapter which is not working or I am doing something wrong.

There is also this another I/O adapter `com.google.cloud.bigtable.beam.CloudBigtableIO` and I am not sure which one to choose.

Some questions:

1. Which adapater should I use? --  this is answered, see edit.
2. How do I verify what is going wrong in writing to BigTable? Finding it hard to look into pipeline without those `System.out.println` statements.
3. How is authentication done to write to BigTable by direct-runner? Does the SDK automatically detect the `$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable & use those credentials?

Will be happy to give more details.

**EDIT:**

- Apache Beam Java SDK version: 2.37
- Per the [docs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.37.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigtable/BigtableIO.html#:%7E:text=Please%20note%20the%20Cloud%20BigTable%20HBase%20connector%20available%20here.%20We%20recommend%20using%20that%20connector%20over%20this%20one%20if%20HBase%20API%20works%20for%20your%20needs.), I should be using [this connector](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable-hbase/tree/main/bigtable-dataflow-parent/bigtable-hbase-beam)

Comment: You mentioned that you are using org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigtable.BigtableIO adapter which is not working. Could you mention in details what is the issue you are getting? I mean any error message in specific.

Comment: hiya, my problem was solved today. Turns out, I was not setting proper triggers and allowedLateness during windowing which lead to my `Count.perElement` to never emit results.

Comment: There is no problem with BigTable adapter for now. But to be cautious, I will update my question after some more time of messing around

Comment: Nice to hear your issue got resolved. It will be helpful for the Community members if you can post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**To verify what is going on :**

*1. add in `main()` `BasicConfigurator.configure();`*

*2. add in `pom.xml`*

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.32</version>
</dependency>
```

*3. add this log4j.properities*

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

**To write on bigtable with direct runner**
*1. in `pom.xml` :*

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

*2. the interface for the pipeline option, to configure with run config commands:*

```
public interface RequestsOptions extends PipelineOptions {
    @Description("File path")
    @Validation.Required
    String getInput();

    void setInput(String value);

    @Description("Output")
    @Validation.Required
    String getOutput();

    void setOutput(String value);
}
```

*3. in run config commands:*

```
--project=PROJECT_ID
--dataset=DATASET_NAME
--inputFile=INPUT_FILE_NAME
--region=REGION_TO_RUN //if dataflow runner
--runner=YOUR_SELECTED_RUNNER
--tempLocation=GOOGLE_STORAGE_LOCATION(to save temp files)
```